# Is $404$ a palindrome in base negative $31$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, palindrome

I was browsing on a website and I accidentally clicked on a link ([Here is the link](https://brilliant.org/algebra/classical-inequalities/classical-inequality-statements/cauchy-schwarz-inequality/), but it may not show the same thing). The following was written there:

> $404$ is also a palindrome in base negative $31$.

Firstly, I have always known that number bases are always positive. So, how is a negative number base defined? And is it really true that $404$ is also a palindrome in base $-31$? This also arises the following question in my mind:

> Can any number (palindrome or non-palindrome) be written as a palindrome in some base?

I found that a number $n$ is equal to $11$ in base $(n-1)$, which is a two-digit palindrome. So, this seems to be true (please correct me if I am wrong). So, let's modify the above question for negative numbers that is "can any number (palindrome or non-palindrome) be written as a palindrome in some negative base"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base

Comment: And yes, $4\cdot 10^2 + 0\cdot 10^1 + 4\cdot 10^0 = 1\cdot(-31)^2 + 18\cdot(-31)^1 + 1\cdot (-31)^0$.

Comment: "Can any number (palindrome or non-palindrome) be written as a palindrome in some base?" Yes. Just pick a base larger than the number, and the number will be a single digit.

Comment: Somewhat less trivially, let $n>0$, then $n^2-n+1$ will be a palindrome in base $-n$.

Comment: Well if you divide $404\div (-31)= -13.0322...$ and if we round down to have a positive remainder we have $404 = -13\times (-31) + 1$.  Now to make that $-13$ positive we can "borrow" from $(-31)^2 = 31^2$.  That is to say $-13\times (-31)=(-31 + 18)\times (-31)= (-31)^2 + 18(-31)$.  So $404 = -13\times(-31) + 1 = 1\times (-31)^2 + 18\times(-31) + 1$.  And although it is *wacky* it follows all the rules of positive bases (except what the range of digits are) and we can say $404=(1)(18)(1)_{-31}$ which... is a palindrome.

Comment: In base ($1-n$), $1(n-2)1$ is $(1-n)^2+(n-2)(1-n)+1=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a positive base $k$, we can write any number $x$ out in the form $\sum_{i=-m}^na_ik^i$ for some positive integers $m,n$ and $0\le a_i<k$, allowing $m=\infty$ if necessary. For instance, with $k=10,x=13.214$, we have $m=3,n=2,a_{-2}=4,a_{-1}=1,a_0=2,a_1=3,a_2=1$. The case $m=\infty$ occurs if you have a non-terminating decimal expansion (e.g. $k=10,x=1/3,n=0,m=\infty,a_i=1$ for $i<0$).

This generalises to negative $k$ too: no part of the definition needs to be changed. (But we will have to start asking questions about whether every real number can be written uniquely in base $k$.) For $k=-31$, the last digit before the (no-longer-)decimal place is still a unit, but the digit before has value $-31$, and the next one $(-31)^2$ and so on. For instance, the base $-31$ value $345.6$ means $3\times (-31)^2+4\times -31+5\times 31^0 + 6\times 31^{-1}$.

Observe that $404=(-31)^2+18\times-31+1$, so it has digits (from right to left) $1$, $18$ and $1$. (To write this as a single number we might use $a=10,b=11,\dots,z=35$ to get $404_{10}=1i1_{-31}$.) This is a palindrome.

Your last question, "Can any number (palindrome or non-palindrome) be written as a palindrome in some base?", has an even more trivial answer than the one you give: a number $x$ is a single digit in base $x+1$, so yes. As for the negative base, there are again lots of trivial answers: try base $-(x+1)$ and we will again have a single digit number.